# Missing closing slash for rel="canonical"

Tags: jquery, html, css, seo

I have added the `<link rel="canonical" href="{$ogUrl}" />`  within my page's head tag but when i view the page source the closing slash is missing and the output comes as below

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.XXX.com/">
```

Can someone suggest me what could be the issue.

Comment: then why do we not get the closing slash any reasons for it?

Comment: @Sweta By "View source", I assumed that you were using an inspector like Webkit Inspector. It's perfectly HTML5-valid to drop off the slash, so to enhance readability, it's omitted. If you view the real View source (CTRL + U in Chrome/Firefox), then you'll see that the slash is still there. Visit http://validator.w3.org/ if you're really worried about the validity of your page.

Comment: I'm viewing the page source using CTRL+U and the output comes without the slash

Comment: What tool are you using to serve the (static) HTML pages?

Answer (score 0):

As Rob W mentioned, this is not an issue. Your browser does change it that way.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the syntax without the slash is the correct one.

Comment: @MrLister: I have added the trailing slash for canonical element in my code but it doesn't reflect when i view the page source from the browser (CTRL+U).